# Git unexpected end of JSON inputB/s when pushing

Tags: git, git-lfs

I'm seeing the following error when i try and push a file to git.

```
Remote "origin" does not support the LFS locking API. Consider disabling it with:
  $ git config lfs.https://gitlab.foobar.fr/templates/scrape.git/info/lfs.locksverify false
batch request: unexpected end of JSON inputB/s                                  
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@gitlab.foobar.fr:/templates/scrape.git'
```

I can pull and commit other files to the repo, what is the issue?

Comment: Side note: the visible output is the result of one program writing `... KiB/s` and a carriage return, and then another program writing `batch request: unexpected end of JSON input\n` over top of the first program's output. That overwrote everything up through `Ki` but left `B/s` at the end of the line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

LFS was not active on the repo, and thus the LFS Locking API was not supported.

To resolve this in GitLab, I activated :

`Settings > General > Visibility, project features, permissions > Git Large File Storage (LFS)`

This enabled LFS on the repo.